# Is it possible to add iTerm2 shortcut for custom input?

Tags: terminal, command-line, iterm

It is common in text editors to have special line break that doesn't create new paragraph. Usually with <kbd>⌥ Option</kbd><kbd>⏎ Return</kbd> shortcut. I want to achieve something similar but in terminal:

on <kbd>⌥ Option</kbd><kbd>⏎ Return</kbd> instead of inserting new line I want to insert <kbd>Space</kbd> </kbd> + new line ( `\\n`) so that I can continue to write long command on the next line.

```
git<alt+enter>status<alt+enter>file.txt<enter>
```

```
$ git \
status \
file.txt
```

Comment: Terminal is not a text editor so you can't treat it the same.  Just enter the backslash and press enter.  You'll get a `>` prompt where you can add the next line. Add another backslash for another line or just press enter when done.

Comment: Isn’t it up to the shell to parse the keyboard input and decide what to do or are you asking us to synthesize the \ and enter from a key press? I’m not entirely sure what the “ask” is here.